# Storing data in text files instead of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, text-files

I'm intending to use both of SQL Server and simple text files to save my data.

Information like `Users data` are going to be stored in SQL Server, RSS fedd for each user are going to be stored in folder with the user Id as a title and inside this folder I can put the files that going to store the data in, each file can take only 20 lines, if there is more than 20 then I make a new file.

When I need to reed this data I simply call the last file in the user's folder.

I need to know what is the advantages and disadvantages of using this method?

thanx

Comment: If you have a database, why in the world would you want to store data in text files?  What do YOU see as the advantage of storing some data in text files?

Comment: If I use the database to store these data I need to do Joins between tow freakin HUGE tables which I'll not do in the world, I'm I right ?

Comment: Databases are designed to work efficiently with large amounts of data.  Store it in text files and you will just be writing code to do the same thing yourself, and I guarantee it will be less efficient.

Comment: But you didn't give me any reason to prove that ?

Comment: You're solving a problem that doesn't exist. Just put the data in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to store the text file data into either VARCHAR(8000) or Blob and store inside the table in database.

The advantages of storing in database is:

- All your data is stored in a single place. It is very  easy for you to backup and restore in other place, if required
- Database by default comes with concurrency and if you have say multiple users trying to access the same row, same table, database handles it inherently
- When you go for files and database kind of hybrid approach, you are going for distributed storage and you have to always make sure that they are consistent
- If you want to just store the latest text file content, go for UPDATE. If you want to keep history of earlier text files content, go for SCD Type 2 kind of storage or go for historical table containing previous text file data
- Database is a single contained unit and you can do so many things on it like : Transparent data encryption, masking, access control and all security related stuff in a single contained unit. In hybrid approach, you have to manage security in two places.
- When all your data is in a single place, and once you have proper indexes, you can write queries and come up with so many different reporting use cases, using SQL. But, if the data is distributed, you have to manage how will be handling the different reporting use cases.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not quite correct.
You should start with clarification of requirements for the application. Answer to yourself the following questions:

- What type of data queries need to be executed (selects, updates, reports).
- How many users will be. How often requests from them will be coming. Does data must be synchronized across users (Concurrency).
- Need of authentication and authorization, localization.
- Need for modification history support.
- Etc.

Databases usually have all this mechanisms and you do not have to implement them in your application.

Depending on your application needs you decide what strategy to use for storing the data: by means of database, files, or by both approaches.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31901777)